# Combining rows with overlapping dates in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some data similar to the below:

#### Base data

```
Student Start Date  End Date    Course
John    01-Jan-20   30-Sep-20   Business
John    01-Jan-20   30-Dec-20   Psychology
John    01-Oct-20   NULL        Music
Jack    01-Feb-20   30-Sep-20   Business
Jack    01-Apr-20   30-Nov-20   Music
```

I want to transform the data so I have a row for each student, for each time period, with a concatenated list of courses, i.e.

#### Target output

```
Student Start Date  End Date    Course
John    01-Jan-20   30-Sep-20   Business, Psychology
John    01-Oct-20   30-Dec-20   Psychology, Music
John    01-Jan-21   NULL        Music
Jack    01-Feb-20   31-Mar-20   Business
Jack    01-Apr-20   30-Sep-20   Business, Music
Jack    01-Oct-20   30-Nov-20   Music
```

I have a script that works if the dates are identical, using STUFF on the course field and grouping on student/dates (code below). But I can't work out how to handle the overlapping dates?

```
Select Student,
       Courses =
       STUFF((select ',' + course
              from Table1 b
              where a.student = b.student
              for XML PATH('')
              ),1,1,''
             )
        
        from table1 a
        Group by student
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Have you had a look at `STRING_AGG`? There are plenty of examples of how to create delimited results in SQL Server on Stack Overflow, why didn't those examples help you?

Comment: @Larnu this is more than a string agg problem, it also requires a gaps and islands component

Comment: @Larnu - Scattergunning comments without actually understanding the question doesn't help anyone.  By all means point them in the right direction to find the solution themselves, but giving them the smallest bit of the simplest part of the solution (that they are already able to do per their mention of `stuff`) because you didn't properly read the question is not constructive.  A link to [something that explains how to do the part they are struggling with](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9130/sql-server-window-functions-gaps-and-islands-problem/) would have actually been helpful.

Comment: I've added my current code that creates the delimited output for courses. As @Larnu says that's not the part I'm struggling with, it's the dates element. Thanks for the constructive help Larnu - I shall review that link and see if I can progress further

Comment: @Roo no worries, have a crack at the gaps and islands and if you're still stuck amend your question and give me a ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little long winded, as you need to get the groups for the dates. As the dates don't overlap, you then need to do a bit of elimination of some of the groupings too, so it takes a couple of sweeps.

I use CTEs to get the groups I need, and then use a subquery to string aggregate (on a more recent version of SQL Server you can use `STRING_AGG` and not need a second scan of the table). This ends up with this:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('John',CONVERT(date,'01-Jan-20'),CONVERT(date,'30-Sep-20'),'Business'),
                ('John',CONVERT(date,'01-Jan-20'),CONVERT(date,'30-Dec-20'),'Psychology'),
                ('John',CONVERT(date,'01-Oct-20'),CONVERT(date,NULL),'Music'),
                ('Jack',CONVERT(date,'01-Feb-20'),CONVERT(date,'30-Sep-20'),'Business'),
                ('Jack',CONVERT(date,'01-Apr-20'),CONVERT(date,'30-Nov-20'),'Music'))V(Student,StartDate,EndDate,Course)),
Dates AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT V.Student, V.[Date]
    FROM YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(YT.Student,YT.StartDate),
                            (YT.Student,YT.EndDate)) V(Student,[Date])),
Islands AS(
    SELECT *,
           LEAD(ISNULL([Date],'99991231')) OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY ISNULL([Date],'99991231')) AS NextDate
    FROM Dates
    WHERE [Date] IS NOT NULL),
Groups AS(
    SELECT I.Student,
           I.Date AS StartDate,
           CASE DATEPART(DAY,I.NextDate) WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, I.NextDate) ELSE I.NextDate END AS EndDate,
           STUFF((SELECT ',' + YT.Course
                  FROM YourTable YT
                  WHERE YT.Student = I.Student
                    AND YT.StartDate <= I.[Date]
                    AND (YT.EndDate >= I.NextDate OR YT.EndDate IS NULL)
                  ORDER BY YT.Course
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS Courses
    FROM Islands I)
SELECT Student,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       Courses
FROM Groups
WHERE ([StartDate] != EndDate OR EndDate IS NULL)
  AND Courses IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Student DESC,
         StartDate ASC;
```